# Setting up relay host for zimbra

Tags: smtp, zimbra

I would like to configure Smtp for my mail server to send out mail to external server. I followed [this link](http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Outgoing_SMTP_Authentication) and confused of what exactly the relay mail should be, `zmprov ms server.domain.com zimbraMtaRelayHost mailrelay.example.com` I did not know what should be use to replay for `mailrelay.example.com`. If my mail domain is `mail.domain.com` so can I set up for relay host as `wiki.domain.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct use would be:

```
zmprov ms <your zimbra server> zimbraMtaRelayHost <the relay-host you're sending mail through>
```

So, if you have installed Zimbra on mail.domain.com and would like to send all mails through wiki.domain.com, you would use

```
zmprov ms mail.domain.com zimbraMtaRelayHost wiki.domain.com
```

Comment: I set my relay host followed your suggestion, unfortunately, I cannot send out mail to external server, only the mail those are in the local can receive mail.

Comment: Did you correctly configure the relay server to accept relaying mails from your zimbra server? You can have a look into its mail log and in Zimbra's /var/log/zimbra.log for error details.

Comment: The log show: `relay=none, delay=0, delays=0/0/0/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for domain loops back to myself)`

Comment: Your relay server thinks, that it should host mail for the domain you're using. You have to remove the domain from the local domains-setting (or whatever it is called in your mail server)

Comment: I set gmail as a relay host and it worked well, so according to you idea I cannot use the local domain as a relay host?

Comment: No, you have to tell your relay server, to NOT handle mail for your domain and rather only relay it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66392/discussion-between-dinhngochien-and-dennis-ploger).